# Using C# and Json.Net for parsing

Tags: c#, json, json.net

An API is returning to me the following json:

```
{
   "query":{
      "pages":{
         "49123":{
            "pageid":49123,
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Phoenix (constellation)",
            "revisions":[
               {
                  "revid":588710862,
                  "parentid":588710834
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I used **json2csharp** to build a class representing this json (I manually tweaked the names for PageInfo, as it was coughing on this name and calling it **__invalid_type__49123**)

```
public class Revision
{
    public int revid { get; set; }
    public int parentid { get; set; }
}

public class PageInfo
{
    public int pageid { get; set; }
    public int ns { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public List<Revision> revisions { get; set; }
}

public class Pages
{
    public PageInfo pageInfo { get; set; }
}

public class Query
{
    public Pages pages { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Query query { get; set; }
}
```

and tried to parse it:

```
        var json = "{\"query\":{\"pages\":{\"49123\":{\"pageid\":49123,\"ns\":0,\"title\":\"Phoenix (constellation)\",\"revisions\":[{\"revid\":588710862,\"parentid\":588710834}]}}}}";
        // unescaped version of json below
        // {"query":{"pages":{"49123":{"pageid":49123,"ns":0,"title":"Phoenix (constellation)","revisions":[{"revid":588710862,"parentid":588710834}]}}}}

        var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

I can examine and see root.query.pages all have values, but pageInfo is null.  I'm not sure what I'm missing that will allow me to load this json into an object.

Comment: It's because `49123` is not mapping to `PageInfo` property inside the `Pages` class. This is an interesting situation here because it looks like that particular element in the `JSON` is the value of the `PageId` so it will be different for each instance of your `JSON` string. If it was a constant, you could've used `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Myname")]` decoration on the `PageInfo` property in the `Pages` class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your class definiton as below. it will work.. (see the definition of `Query` class)

```
public class Revision
{
    public int revid { get; set; }
    public int parentid { get; set; }
}

public class Page
{
    public int pageid { get; set; }
    public int ns { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public List<Revision> revisions { get; set; }
}

public class Query
{
    public Dictionary<string,Page>  pages { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Query query { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the right answer. There's was typo in your answer. `Query` class definition should be as follows.`public class Query
    {
        public Dictionary<string, PageInfo> pages { get; set; }
    }` . I updated your answer. I tested this and it works.

Comment: @Shiva No, there is no `PageInfo` in my code. I rolled back your edit.

Comment: Oh, just saw that you changed OP's `PageInfo` class to `Page` class. I'd copied OP's code and added the `Query` class from your code, not noticing that you'd renamed the `PageInfo` class. My bad.